# How do you see what symbolic links are in a directory?

Tags: command-line

When I try

```
dir /A
```

I see some links but not all. The links I don't see are put there by a startup script from corporate. Is it possible to create a link such that it's visible on the users desktop but they can't even see it in the command line? I'm a tad confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible dupe of [View a list of symbolic links on system?](//superuser.com/q/496092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not talking about symbolic links, which are created using `mklink`, but rather shortcuts. Windows does have a default desktop that can contain shortcuts to programs. Because it's a general directory you won't have write access to it as a normal user.

Check `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` for what seems to be missing.

Comment: That was it! Well, it got rid of two of them anyways. There's still one that I don't see anywhere. I'm not exactly sure what it is. Clicking it opens a windows explorer window and a window for a login to a program that has the same icon as windows explorer. It doesn't show up by `dir /A` or in `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.

Comment: You could right click it and check its properties. The "General" tab might provide the information you need (a path where it's stored). If it's on a company machine they might've setup a GPO. I'm not sure where the shortcut would be stored in that case.

Comment: The properties option in the right click > context menu is missing. I ran outside of my personal time box for this.I guess one day when AGI dominates the planet all computing will be done directly against the metal with zero superfluous personal statements manifesting themselves as unremovable desktop shortcuts. idk, thanks for showing me that directory though. Very useful!